# MVC5 Show pretty Enum DisplayName in @Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, asp.net-mvc-5

In my asp.net MVC5 projekt I'm making use of the [Display(Name="String")] annotation for Enums, which does work well as long as I'm using:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
```

Now I'd like to use my pretty Enum names as link text in an

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Category.ToString(), "Category", new { id = item.Category })
```

It of course works like this, but I dont see the DisplayName value (with spaces). How can I achieve this?

This is what my enums look like (just for clarification):

```
public enum Category
{
    Book,
    Movie,
    [Display(Name = "TV Show")]
    TVShow,
    [Display(Name = "Video Game")]
    Videogame,
    Music,
    Software,
    Other
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public static class EnumExtension
{
    public static string GetDisplayName(this System.Enum en)
    {
        Type type = en.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());
        if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true);
            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
            {
                return ((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).Name;
            }
        }
        return en.ToString();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Category.GetDisplayName(), "Category", new { id = item.Category })
```

Comment: I pasted your code into my model file where also my enums are. I can build the code, but I get squiggly lines and on the site following error: 'System.Nullable<MediaDB.Models.Category>' does not contain a definition for 'GetDescription' accepting a first argument of 'System.Nullable<MediaDB.Models.Category>' could be found.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure MediaDB.Models.Category is enum type? From the exception seems that you allow to have nulls as a category. Try item.Category.Value.GetDescription() - (of course check if item.Category.HasValue before).
Make sure, you have a reference to the EnumExtension class in your view.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the @using MediaDB.Models; statement in the view. However, is it possible to change this code to make use of the existing [Display(Name = "TV Show")] annotation, as I use those anyway. Otherwise I'd have to include the same string twice.